# Create a torrent with Transmission doesn't work

Tags: transmission, utorrent, torrent

I try to create my own torrent with transmission in command line.

I follow a basic tutorial but I missed something: https://forum.transmissionbt.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&p=55854

```
transmission-create --comment "my comment" --tracker "udp://tracker.openb ittorrent.com:80/announce" --outfile test.torrent MyFile.txt
Creating torrent "test.torrent" ..... done!
```

And

```
transmission-show test.torrent

Name: MyFile.txt
File: test.torrent

GENERAL

  Name: MyFile.txt
  Hash: 67bd20d96046a0a80753fc6f0c93006077f99d7d
  Created by: Transmission/2.52 (13304)
  Created on: Sun Aug  3 12:31:29 2014
  Comment: my comment
  Piece Count: 1574
  Piece Size: 32.00 KiB
  Total Size: 51.57 MB
  Privacy: Public torrent

TRACKERS

  Tier #1
  udp://tracker.openbittorrent.com:80/announce

FILES

  MyFile.txt
```

Ok now, when i upload the torrent on my computer, i use utorrent. He blocks to :

> Connection to pairs 0%

Basically i have this :

[image]

So i'm sure i have doing something wrong, or forgot something but i can't find what...